# RandomizedSearchCV precision score doesn't match in Random Forest

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, grid-search

I am trying to carry out some hyperparameters optimization on a **random forest** using `RandomizedSearchCV`. I set the scoring method as **average precision**. The `rand_search.best_score_` is around **0.38** (a reasonable result for my dataset), but when I compute the same average precision score using `rand_search.best_estimator_` the result is close to **1** (see below).

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
randsearch = RandomizedSearchCV(clf,
                                scoring='average_precision',
                                param_distributions=parameters,
                                n_iter=1,
                                cv=StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=10),
                                n_jobs=1, 
                                verbose=2)

randsearch.fit(X, y)
randomized_best_score = randsearch.best_score_

best_estimator_avg_precision = average_precision_score(y, 
                               randsearch.best_estimator_.predict(X))

best_estimator_avg_precision_probs = average_precision_score(y, 
                          randsearch.best_estimator_.predict_proba(X)[:, 1])

print(randomized_best_score)
print(best_estimator_avg_precision)
print(best_estimator_avg_precision_probs)

>>> randomized_best_score: 0.3836
>>> best_estimator_avg_precision: 0.983577210629
>>> best_estimator_avg_precision_probs: 1.0
```

Any idea why this can happen? What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things to note here.

1) `randsearch.best_score_` is the mean score for test folds over training data, so will not match when you use full data to calculate score.

2) The RandomizedSearchCV will be trained on (fitted) whole data after finding the best combination of params (The combination of params which produced the `best_score_`). So when you score on the same data, it is expected to give higher results.

3) When you specify `scoring='average_precision'`, internally its converted to the following:

```
average_precision_scorer = make_scorer(average_precision_score,
                                       needs_threshold=True)
```

The param `needs_threshold` is `True` here, that means the scorer requires the output of `predict_proba()` or `decision_function()` from the estimator. So your second output `best_estimator_avg_precision` is not comparable.

And for your `best_estimator_avg_precision_probs`, do this to check if it makes any difference:-

```
best_estimator_avg_precision_probs = average_precision_score(y, 
                      randsearch.best_estimator_.predict_proba(X))
```

But still, the scores will be higher because of point 2.